# SQL: pivot dates and hours without aggregate function

Tags: sql, date, pivot

I have a collection of dates and hours, I'd like pivot this information by the date and show the hours inside.

[image]

The problem is the aggregate function, I'm compelled to put a max/min function in the hour column, resulting this:

[image]

I need something like this, but the hours instead the dates (order by hours)

[image]

I'm using:

```
SELECT GtDesc, ErrDesc,  [05/02/2018], [06/02/2018], [07/02/2018], [08/02/2018], [09/02/2018], [12/02/2018]
FROM(
SELECT  ErrDesc, GtDesc, CONVERT(VARCHAR, dt, 103) 'DateTrans', FORMAT(dt, 'hh:mm tt') 'HourTrans',
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By GtDesc, ErrDesc, dt Order By dt)
FROM    Trans t
INNER JOIN Gates g ON g.CID = t.CID
WHERE   ( dt >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '5/02/2018 7:00 AM', 103) AND dt <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/02/2018 7:00 PM', 103) )
) AS PivotData
PIVOT(
    MAX(DateTrans)
    FOR [DateTrans] IN (
      [05/02/2018], [06/02/2018], [07/02/2018], [08/02/2018], [09/02/2018], [12/02/2018]
    )
) AS PivotTable
```

What kind of change I need in my query?

Comment: Do you have to do this in T-SQL? A Pivot Table in Excel, or a Matrix in SSRS would make this far easier.

Comment: can you change MAX(DateTrans) to MAX(HoursTrans)

Comment: @PrabhathAmaradasa MAX(HoursTrans) returns 1 row (2nd image in the example), I need to show all hours

Comment: @csotelo you can do a crossjoin with the original table and the pivot with MAX(HoursTrans)  results and add case statements to set other values to null

Comment: @PrabhathAmaradasa the problem is, if exists more than 1 hour-record in one day, the max function will show the last hour.

Comment: @csotelo try this one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1e220/16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
    WITH data_CTE(iid, COL0,COL1,RID,ErrDesc, GtDesc)
AS

(

SELECT id, DateTrans, HourTrans,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (DateTrans)ORDER BY  id) AS RID ,ErrDesc, GtDesc
  FROM Gates

)

SELECT ErrDesc, GtDesc, [05/22/2018], [06/02/2018], [07/02/2018], [08/02/2018]

FROM

(SELECT  COL0,COL1,RID ,ErrDesc, GtDesc

FROM data_CTE)C

PIVOT

(

max(COL1)

FOR COL0 IN ( [05/22/2018], [06/02/2018], [07/02/2018], [08/02/2018])

) AS PivotTable;
```

Here is the [Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1e220/15) link.This is not the exact order you want.

Answer (score 0):

@csotelo, I gather you're trying to do something like this below.

The only problem is that SQL has no facility (without significantly more complex dynamic-SQL approaches) to produce this kind of output dynamically - you'd have to hard-code the logic for every single date.

Also, are the times supposed to progress downwards and across diagonally (as in your image), or is each day's time supposed to start on the top row?

```
WITH source_table AS
(
    SELECT  
        ,GtDesc
        ,ErrDesc
        ,dt
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, dt, 103)  AS DateTrans
        ,FORMAT(dt, 'hh:mm tt')     AS HourTrans

    FROM
        Trans AS t

    INNER JOIN
        Gates AS g
        ON (g.CID = t.CID)

    WHERE 
        dt BETWEEN (CONVERT(DATETIME, '5/02/2018 7:00 AM', 103)) AND (CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/02/2018 7:00 PM', 103))
)
,source_table_ext AS
(
    SELECT 
        GtDesc
        ,ErrDesc
        ,dt
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GtDesc, ErrDesc, DateTrans ORDER BY dt) AS date_line_num
        ,DateTrans
        ,HourTrans
    FROM source_table
)
,pivoted_table AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM source_table_ext PIVOT (
        MAX(HourTrans)
        FOR DateTrans IN (
             [05/02/2018]
            ,[06/02/2018]
            ,[07/02/2018]
            ,[08/02/2018]
            ,[09/02/2018]
            ,[12/02/2018]
            ) 
    ) AS pvt
)

SELECT
    GtDesc
    ,ErrDesc
    ,MAX([05/02/2018]) AS [05/02/2018]
    ,MAX([06/02/2018]) AS [06/02/2018]
    ,MAX([07/02/2018]) AS [07/02/2018]
    ,MAX([08/02/2018]) AS [08/02/2018]
    ,MAX([09/02/2018]) AS [09/02/2018]
    ,MAX([12/02/2018]) AS [12/02/2018]

FROM
    pivoted_table

GROUP BY
    GtDesc, ErrDesc, date_line_num

ORDER BY
    GtDesc, ErrDesc, date_line_num
```